# Would Aragorn have been able to resist the Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-one-ring

Despite leaving Frodo and Sam to finish what the Fellowship started, would Aragorn had he had the Ring been able to control it without falling to Sauron's will and becoming his servant? Was there a chance Aragorn could have been strong enough as a Númenórean from a royal bloodline of faithful Númenóreans, most notably Elendil and Isildur? (I know Isildur fell to it).

Is this what Sauron feared most about him, the fact that he was a strong-willed heir of the man who cut the ring from his finger? Could he in fact resist the Ring's attempt to corrupt him? Or would he have eventually caved and fallen like Isildur did?

Comment: Even Gandalf would have fallen. In any case, had any but Gandalf attempted to contend directly with Sauron,  Ring or no Ring,  they would have been defeated.

Comment: It's extremely clear that what Sauron fears most is a powerful character claiming the ring as his own and overthrowing him. The idea that someone might want to destroy the ring doesn't occur to him. He would have feared Aragorn for that reason.

Comment: As a human it would've been impossible,Isildur;Aragorns ancestor,a pure blooded Numenor king & 1  of the most powerful men to ever walk Middle Earth couldn't resist it & Aragorn is said to much like him;so no he wouldn't be able to resist it,i think he realizes it too & that's why he refuses to touch it.

Comment: Not even a hobbit could resist it. They of all people, were the most resistant to the lures of power, and Smeagol and even Frodo were tempted by it. As the opening monologue says, nine rings were given to the race of **men, who above all else desire power**." Given enough time, even men like Aragorn or Faramir would have fallen to it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As it stands nobody would have been immune to the ring. Only the time that the ring needed to corrupt someone is different and depends on the person (and seemingly also on the race). A Dwarf would fall differently than most others while Hobbits seem a bit more resistant than others.

But in the end everyone even the Wizards would have fallen to the dark influence of the ring.

So no, Aragon would not have been immune. With his strong will he probably would have been able to resist longer than the average Man (it is unknown if (partial) Elven heritage also prolongs this time or not), but in the end he would have fallen like his ancestor.

Comment: Just ask the nine nazgul

Comment: It affects people differently the Nazgul were enslaved to it,Gandalf or Saruman could've controlled the Nazgul,im not sure if Aragorn could if he possesed the ring.

Comment: @turinsbane Frodo couldn't control the Nazgul and he seemed to be the most resilient one ring bearer we saw so far

Comment: Tom Bombadil was immune to the  Ring.  Giving it to him would just have been dangerous for different reasons, as explained in the Council of Elrond.

Comment: @suchiuomizu are you sure about the immunity? (source?) as taht would mean that tom would be way more resilient than even wizards / Maya.

Comment: @Thomas Bombadil was in the Middle Earth before the arrival of the Maia, even Melkor himself. He's apparently immune to the One Ring, since it has no power over him and can't make him invisible.

Comment: @Thomas i mean it is heavily implied  to be so powerful tom could walk over to mordor if he so chooses and kick Sauron in the nuts and walk away unscathed

Comment: Not sure where you pick up that implication. Tom himself did not believe he had any power over the Black Riders, let alone Sauron. Gandalf(?) points out that he believes  that the Ring had no power over Tom, rather than Tom having any power over the Ring.